# How do i recover my ubuntu back?

Tags: software-installation, upgrade, login-screen, kali

I mixed kali linux source list with my ubuntu sources list and tried updating ubuntu and full upgrading it. After a reboot now I am facing some problems I can not login every thing is mixed up, how can I go back to my ubuntu.

Comment: It's time to backup and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

So if you are saying that you added a Kali Linux alongside your Ubuntu sources, then I would assume it succesfully applied Kali updates to Ubuntu resulting in a broken OS. I suggest you look into how to repair Ubuntu with an Ubuntu live install disk, matching the Ubuntu version you currently have installed.